# Scala Multiclass classification with labeled point

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I have a multiclass classification problem I'm looking to sort with logistic regression. I know this can also be tackled by decision trees and random forest, but wish to stick specifically with "LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS".
I have all the data tidying done. I have my data nice and tidy in a dataframe with a:
label field (String), a feature vector (vector of features/ numbers) and a third column "LabelIndex" (numbers representing the class).

When I do a train test split on the data frame and try to fit it to: LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

```
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().setNumClasses(10).setIntercept(true).setValidateData(true).run("trainingData")
```

It doesn't like the "run" part.

The example I am working off, loads a data file in via:

```
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(Spark.sparkContext, "data/mnist.bz2")
```

(i'm trying to copy the example, and slot in my own data. But its in a different format, looks different etc)
I was doing a bit of reading, and I'd come across, I need to convert my dataframe to a RDD[LabeledPoint].
I need to map it.

I'm having problems finding good info on how to do this.

How do I simply convert a Dataframe with 3 fields as described above, "Label" (String), "Features" (feature vector), "IndexedLabel" (Double)
into a RDD[LabeledPoint]?

Comment: are you using ML or MLlib?

Comment: ^^ please update the question with the appropriate tag - `apache-spark-ml` or `apache-spark-mllib`.

Comment: I am using: import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

Comment: I found this: and got the dataframe into labeledpoint format/instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882444/cant-convert-dataframe-to-labeled-point

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:

[Can't convert Dataframe to Labeled Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882444/cant-convert-dataframe-to-labeled-point)

This link showed me how to make the conversion successfully.